# Using vb.net How do I return a MySql value of a query and save result as a string

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I just need the value of the query to be saved as String. I can't seem to find a way to grab the data the way i need it.

```
Public Class frmEndJob
    Friend Sub goBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles goBtn.Click      
        Dim mName As String
        mName = frmMain.SWOT.ExecuteSQL("SELECT cMachine FROM machine WHERE cidMachine=`" & machineName.SelectedValue & "`")
    End Sub
End Class
```

My DB info is being saved in frmMain

```
Imports SQL_Database

Public Class frmMain
    Public SWOT As cMySQL = New cMySQL("server=fake; user id=faker; password=fakePw; database=faekDB; pooling=false; allow user variables=true; oldguids=true")   
End Class
```

Comment: We cant see what `cMySQL` is or how it works, so we can only guess.  It looks like a so-called SQL helper.  If it is not working, fix it or get rid of it.

Comment: it is a SQL helper, it is working. I use it in other forms. I use it so I don't have to make the connection every time I make a mysql command. If there was a smarter way I would appreciate your knowledge.

Comment: DbConnections are supposed to be created, used and disposed in the smallest possible scope.  But thats secondary, describe what you mean by `I can't seem to find a way to grab the data the way i need it.` Is there a name coming back? If so the "helper" is working, so whats the problem?  If not, we cant help because we cant see that code

Comment: This code is crazy vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn we use it internally. But I ended up learning how to make it safe from sql injections. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Most successful hacks are from internal users.